# Incomprehensible "Null type mismatch"

Tags: java

Can anybody explain why the print-statement within the loop produces an error
(Null type mismatch: required '@NonNull SortedSet' but the provided value is specified as @Nullable) and the one outside the loop does not.

I expect that this is a Java bug. Is there a workaround that does not involve disabling the nullchecks? (The code makes no sense, it just reproduces the problem).

```
public class Test
{
  static void print(PrintStream ps, @Nullable SortedSet<IState> states)
  {
    if (states != null)
    {
      ps.print(Utility.getElt(0, states));
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < 1; q++)
    {
      if (states != null)
      {
        ps.print(Utility.getElt(0, states));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Utility.getElt has following signature:

```
public static <@Nullable T> T getElt(int idx, @NonNull SortedSet<T> set);
```

If I remove the @NonNull annotation for getElt the problem disappears, but I really want a nonnull 'set' here.

And indeed the annotations are taken from org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.

Comment: please post the code of Utility.getElt() also. What's the return type of that method?

Comment: if those annotations are from `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation` package, I don't think it's a Java bug. What is the signature of `Utility#getElt`?

Comment: @PhuongNguyen The return type is not at issue here; it is the annotation on the second formal argument of `getElt()`, which is `@NonNull SortedSet`.

Comment: @scriptin: question edited with requested info

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm), during null analysis,

> Depending on this option, the compiler will issue either an error or a warning whenever one of the following situations is detected:
>
> > A method declared with a nonnull annotation returns a nullable expression.
> >
> > **A nullable expression is passed as an argument in a method call where the corresponding parameter of the called method is declared with a nonnull annotation.**
> >
> > A nullable expression is assigned to a local variable that is declared with a nonnull annotation.
> >
> > A method that overrides an inherited method declared with a nonnull annotation tries to relax that contract by specifying a nullable annotation (prohibition of contravariant return).
> >
> > A method that overrides an inherited method which has a nullable declaration for at least one of its parameters, tries to tighten that null contract by specifying a nonnull annotation for its corresponding parameter (prohibition of covariant parameters).
>
> In the above an expression is considered as nullable if either it is statically known to evaluate to the value null, or if it is declared with a nullable annotation.

(emphasis added). In your case, you are trying to pass a `Nullable` value to a `NonNull` parameter.

Comment: Explain the inconsistency of error appearing on one invocation, but not on the other---that's the actual question.

Comment: Also, your last quoted sentence: `an expression is considered as nullable if either it is statically known to evaluate to the value null`---the expression at hand is known *not to evaluate to null*. That would pretty much make it a non-nullable expression.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is optimizing away the duplication of code outside and inside the loop by running the loop an extra time? What does the compiled bytecode look like?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm

Comment: @Jules The compiler is not allowed to optimize away a formal error. From a practical standpoint, almost no optimization is done at the bytecode level; that's the JIT compiler's concern.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the annotation jar to the most recent(?) version I needed to change the signature of getElt from

```
public static <@Nullable T> T getElt(int idx, @NonNull SortedSet<T> set);
```

to

```
public static @Nullable <T> T getElt(int idx, @NonNull SortedSet<T> set);
```

The previous syntax is no longer valid.

This did not fix the problem, but at least there is now a workaround by explicit casting (still only required for the version that is inside the loop!):

```
    ps.print(Utility.getElt(q, (@NonNull SortedSet<IState>)states));
```

Although this results in the wonderful warning
"Unnecessary cast from SortedSet to SortedSet", it is just a warning now, not an error.

This null-checking in Eclipse still seems to be very much "work in progress".
My previous version of the annotation jar was not very old.